# How can I retrieve the amount of spaces in a paragraph in PHP?

Tags: php

Say I had the following:

```
$name= "albert slevir inshten";
```

For the above, I would get 3.

Comment: have you tried `substr_count` before?

Comment: it looks as though there are only 2 spaces in that string.

Answer (score 6):

PHP provides a function called [`substr_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) that counts the amount of occurrences of the passed-in substring:

```
$count = substr_count($str, ' '); //2
```

To retrieve the number of words, you'd use [`str_word_count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php):

```
$count = str_word_count($str); //3
```

Answer (score 3):

to count occurances of substring, use:
[`substr_count()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

to count number of words, use:
[`str_word_count()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)

Answer (score 0):

see [count_chars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php).

Answer (score 0):

I think there are only 2 spaces in this example...

Suggesting the following:

```
$no = count(explode(" ",$str))-1;
```

You can leave the -1 behind if you want the know the number of words (like 3 in your example)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function called `substr_count()`, you can use it like this:

```
$name= "albert slevir inshten";

echo substr_count($name, ' ');
```